# How to relate Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector to eccentricity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, geometry, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

So the eccentricity can be written in this form
$$\mathbf{e}=\frac{\mathbf{A}}{mk}
=\frac{1}{mk}(\mathbf{p}\times\mathbf{L})-\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$
but I cannot find a proof or figure it out on my own.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: If you understood the trivial derivation of [Kepler orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace–Runge–Lenz_vector#Derivation_of_the_Kepler_orbits), you just see, by inspection, that |A| is proportional to the eccentricity...

Answer (score 0):

The force is $-mkr^{-2}\hat{r}$; the special angular momentum is $h=r^2\dot{\theta}$. Since $\vec{L}=mh\hat{k}$ is conserved,$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\vec{p}\times\vec{L}\right)=\vec{F}\times\vec{L}=m^2khr^{-2}\hat{\theta}=m^2k\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}=m^2k\frac{d}{dt}\hat{r}.$$This implies $\vec{A}:=\vec{p}\times\vec{L}-mk\hat{r}$ is conserved. Since$$Ar\cos\theta=\vec{A}\cdot\vec{r}=\vec{r}\cdot\vec{p}\times\vec{L}-mkr=L^2-mkr\implies r=\frac{L^2}{mk}\frac{1}{1+\frac{A}{mk}\cos\theta},$$the eccentricity is $\frac{A}{mk}$. Thus $\frac{\vec{A}}{mk}$ is a vector of length $|e|$.